# Am I using the On Error and SpecialCells (Empty Rows) in Excel's VBA correctly?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to automate user made filters that are generated for day to day operations. Having only started really learning VBA 24 hours ago, i used a combination of Macro recording as well as a mix of different solutions I found online. The code below is the closest I came to what I needed, but there are some oddities I don't quite understand the circumstances of why they're happening much less any way of fixing them.

I've tried offsetting the rows along with adding or removing one from the bottom with minimal success as it always states a section of it is invalid (i'm guessing because it needs to be defined somewhere but not entirely sure in what format).
What seemed to work the best was a combination of Error handling and specialCells where the script should ignore the value appending portion if nothing is populated in the 2nd row. If there is something populated there, then it would proceed to append a value on the last column but only for empty cells.

```
Columns("A:H").Select

    Selection.AutoFilter

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$800000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*",
_Operator:=xlAnd

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$800000").AutoFilter Field:=8,
Criteria1:="=*In*", _Operator:=xlAnd
```

This is supposed to filter out what I need per tab on the excel. I'm looking
for any documents that have a value in the 2nd column (B) and any documents
that contain "In" on the 8th column (H). The reports generated can vary wildly
in length so i designated 800k as a good threshold.

```
On Error GoTo NoBlanks01
If Range("$A$2:$H$2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 0 Then
Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "InsertValueHere"

Skip01:
On Error Resume NextEnd If
```

I'm not 100% sure if having them this way is redundant but my thinking here
was that if there's anything in the second row, proceed. If not, an error will
be produced and will follow to the bottom of the script then go to skip01 and
proceed from there. Essentially bypassing the value appending where it'll
select all empty cells in row I and append "Insert Value Here". This portion
generally works, but there are some tabs in the excel when there will be items
on the second row, yet the script won't recognize them and proceed through the
error handling. That's the part that I don't understand.

```
NoBlanks01:
Resume Skip01
```

'I have 11 "NoBlanks", "No Skips" and "Resumes" in the same sub. All according
to different tabs. Again, not sure if that matters but figured i'd state that
in case there's some order of operations I missed while researching this.

I expect that the script should filter according to the specifications given, then run through a query where it checks to see if the second row contains any items.
If it does: then it should proceed to select the last column in that tab, select only empty cells within that tab, then code them a value.
If it doesn't: then it should Skip any value appending and move straight to it's relevant "NoBlanks" Followed by it's relevant "Skip".

As it stands, it does complete the logic on some tabs but not on others. I have zero clue why when the second row is clearly populated. I realize that having some of these reports would come in handy so if needed, i can provide it.

Comment: There's a lot of text there, but it's not so clear exactly what you want to do with what's left as visible after filtering.  You're just checking row2 for visible cells, but that only tells you if Row2 is hidden or not, so it's not obvious why that test...

Comment: Sorry, tried to be as descriptive as possible. After the script checks to see if there are any non empty cells in row 2, i'd like it to either skip the next portion where it looks for empty cells in column I or if an error occurs (aka row 2 is empty) it would continue on without skipping the mentioned portion. If it'll help, i can post more of the script. But its basically the same after this section but just for different tabs

Comment: Why check to see if row2 is hidden though ?  That doesn't tell you anything about the other rows.

Comment: The ideal is to see if anything came back from the filter results in row two. I thought that specific command was used to check if any cells in row two contain data, not that they are hidden. Im more than open to suggestions.*edit* i think i see what you mean. So the way its set up, if the filter doesnt bring anything up in row 2, it wont be "visible". So i would need to include all the possible rows it could find?

Comment: What's special about Row2 though?  Why is that gating the next steps?

Comment: Nothing is. Its just the row after the headers that filter out. I assumed it was the best one to dictate whether or not something came back from the filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngVis As Range

Set sht = ActiveSheet

Set rng = sht.Range("a1").CurrentRegion      '<< the range with data and headers
If Application.CountA(rng) = 0 Then Exit Sub '<< exit if have no data...

rng.AutoFilter

rng.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="=*"
rng.AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="=*In*"

'Next line should not throw an error even if all data
'  rows are filtered, since there's always the header row visible
Set rngVis = rng.Columns("I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If rngVis.Count > 1 Then '<< ignore if only the header row...
    rngVis.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "InsertValueHere"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Only question I have now is can i use the same basic syntax to filter arrays advanced filters and greaterthan or equal to values?

I tried this for example but it doesn't seem to recognize it:

`rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
".00*", ".E0*", ".edb", ".L0*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: Are you missing wildcards?  `Array("*.00*", "*.E0*", "*.edb", "*.L0*")`

Comment: Sorry, should have specified they were file extensions. So nope, should be good on wildcards. My mistake was not editing the field numbers so that was boneheaded. So now it recognizes them and filters, but it only filters the last item in the array "*.L0*" to be exact. I double checked the report i'm using to test this on and there are indeed other extensions on there that should come back from the filter. Code stands as: `Filter field:=4, Criteria1:=Array(".00*", ".E0*", ".edb", ".L0*")`

Comment: How about `Operator` ?  `xlFilterValues` ?

Comment: Adding that eliminates everything but .edb. Code stands as: `rng.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=Array(".00*", ".E0*", ".edb", ".L0*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`. Can't say i'm too familiar with what operator and xlfiltervalues do. I'll research on my part *Edit: I don't think it likes the wildcards in there. added a wildcard to edb as a hunch and it eliminated that result as well.

Comment: According to https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/917998-wild-card-unable-use-autofilter-array.html you can have at most two wildcards when using an array to filter.  That's a new one for me...

Comment: Yeah, looked up some other stack overflow threads on it people have gotten around it by using advanced filters which is what I did here to re-mediate it. But all the same, the answer you gave me is working beautifully and the comments you made plus the trial and error i went through gave me some pretty good insight into what each portion of it does. Can't thank you enough sir!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out